# Get MySQL database table row count on Excel as a VBA variable without loading the table on the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table on an Excel sheet with external data from a MySQL database (using the [MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/). I'm going to create a form so the user can pick a date range of data to load but before starting loading I want to tell how many rows are getting loaded with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE date BETWEEN start AND end`.

I can do something like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};UID=user;PWD=user;SERVER=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;DATABASE=dbName;PORT=3306;", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
  .CommandText = Array("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName")
  .Refresh
End With
```

And then get the amount of rows from the cell A2 but what I want is to know if I can only create the connection on VBA without loading the table on the sheet and have the result in a variable. Not looking to load on the sheet, get the value from it and then delete the table.

Somehow changing the destination part to a variable or doing something like this (can't get it to work):

```
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection 'or As ODBC.Connection
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection 'or New ODBC.Connection
Cn.Open With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};UID=user;PWD=user;SERVER=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx;DATABASE=dbName;PORT=3306;"
'...
```

**Edit:**

For future reference (mostly once I forget and need this again) download [MySQL Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.3.html) preferably the 32-bit version as the 64-bit version might not show the driver (`MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver`) on Excel/Microsoft Query's list (it did show on `C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\odbcad32.exe` though). Then on VBA, menu/dropdown `Tools`, option `References...`, check `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library` (or the latest version available) and use the code from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49287995) like this (change at least `dbName` and `tableName`):

```
Sub Test()
  Dim c As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim sq As String
  Dim strConnectionString As String
  Dim result As Long
  strConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};UID=root;PWD=;SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=dbName;PORT=3306;"
  sq = "SELECT Count(*) As row_count FROM tableName;"
  Set c = New ADODB.Connection
  c.Open strConnectionStringstring
  Set rst = c.Execute(sq)
  result = rst!row_count
  c.Close
  'MsgBox c.Errors
  MsgBox result
End Sub
```

**Another edit:**

Code compacted:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  conn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};UID=user;PWD=user;SERVER=192.168.20.198;DATABASE=dbName;PORT=3306;"
  MsgBox conn.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) As row_count FROM tableName;")!row_count
  conn.Close
  On Error GoTo 0
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox "An error has occurred while connecting to the server. Verify your internet connection." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Error:" & Chr(10) & Err.Number & Chr(10) & Err.Source & Chr(10) & Err.Description
End Sub
```

`!row_count` can be changed to `.Fields("row_count")`

`conn.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) As row_count FROM tableName;")!row_count` can be changed to `conn.Execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName;").Fields("COUNT(*)")`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but you can use standard ADO code to get the record count without interacting with any Excel objects at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some generic code you can adapt.

```
Sub valueFromRecordset()
    ' ========================================================
    ' jdoxey
    '
    ' ensure reference is set to Microsoft ActiveX DataObjects library (the latest version of it).
    '
    ' ========================================================

    Dim c As ADODB.Connection           ' a connection object
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset          ' a recordset object
    Dim sq As String                    ' Sql to execute
    Dim strConnectionString As String   ' string to store connection string
    Dim result As Long                  ' long to store count of records

    ' Set to your connection string
    strConnectionString = "<your connection string>"

    ' Put your SQL here
    sq = "SELECT Count(<column>) As row_count FROM <table>;"

    Set c = New ADODB.Connection        ' create new connection
    c.Open strConnectionString          ' open the connection using connection string
    Set rst = c.Execute(sq)             ' execute the sql file contents and set result set
    result = rst!row_count              ' put value of returned record into variable
    c.Close                             ' close the connection
    'Debug.Print c.Errors
    MsgBox (result)

End Sub
```

NOTE: you need to set the alias of the record count column to `row_count` in your SQL for the code above to work.